# get results from one to one relationship

Tags: laravel-5

I make one to one relationship between two table. One for employees and other for their timesheet.
When I want to see the employee hours is not working ! So far I just enter hours through phpmyadmin.

```js
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('timesheets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('starz_id');
            //starz = employee. I just name it starz

            for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++){
                $table->integer('Jan'.$i)->nullable();
            }

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">

    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        @for($i=1;$i<=14;$i++)
            <td>Jan{{$i}}</td>
        @endfor
        <td>Total</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        @foreach($timesheet as $one)
            <td>
                {{$one->starz->name}}
            </td>

            @for($i=1;$i<=14;$i++)
                <td>
                    {{ $one->Jan.$i }}
                </td>
            @endfor
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

The resutl

```
Name    Jan1    Jan2    Jan3    Jan4    Jan5    Jan6    Jan7    Jan8     Jan9   Jan10   Jan11   Jan12   Jan13   Jan14   Total

ali     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14
```

Also I need to know please what is the right way to calculate the actual time. For ex: I want latter make function that caculate the actual hours working hours spent from start time (9am) and end time(6.30pm).  How can I do this by laravel ?

Answer (score 0):

i think what you want to achieve could have been done in other terms and it was gonna be easier for u. Allow me to write something for you

**Employee.php**

```
public class Employee{
    public timesheets(){
        return $this->hasMany(TimeSheet::class, 'starz_id');
    }
}
```

**TimeSheet.php**

```
public class TimeSheet{
    public employee(){
        return $this->belongsTo(TimeSheet::class, 'starz_id');
    }
}
```

**timesheet migration**

```
Schema::create('timesheets', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('starz_id');
    //now from your form i will encourage you log in an employee using their entry and exit time
    $table->string('date')->nullable();
    $table->string('entry_time')->nullable();
    $table->string('exit_time')->nullable;
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

with this you can use PHP to calculate the time worked maybe using Carbon library. 
on rendering the employee time sheet you can improvise using some other logic. Looks like looping is you favorite

Your logic above will work but its not every month that has 31 days